# Ubuntu 18.04 with LAMP installed and want to upgrade from php7.2 to php7.2-fpm

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php, php7, php-fpm

I have a bare metal Ubuntu 18.04 box that I installed LAMP on for NextCloud and Minecraft dynmap install in vhosts. Everything works okay, but my NextCloud speeds are laughably slow and all the reading I've done says I should have used `php-fpm` instead of vanilla `php`.

I have searched and searched on how to *upgrade* PHP 7.2 to the FPM version and I've come up empty handed. I can't seem to find any information on whether my `php.ini` can be pasted over, how to tell Apache to use the new version and not the old version, whether or not I have to tell each vhost independently to use it of it's an Apache config somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling `php7.2-fpm apache2` will reveal many guides to configure apache.

***NOTE*** ---I do not claim this to be the proper or most secure settings.
The issue of site security is complex and constantly evolving. It is up to you to keep up to date on the best security practices.

This is the method I successfully used the set up in a ***development*** environment.
This assumes default Ubuntu 18.04 LAMP server settings with php7.2 installed.
Method is simalar for release standard php or php7.3 and php7.4(with ppa REPOs configured)

If you do not have one first create a php info page.

```
echo '<?php phpinfo() ?>' | sudo tee /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

Check page in browser via local network or gui if installed on server.
 `"server ip or domain"/phpinfo.php`

The line 'Server API' will confirm default 'Apache 2.0 Handler'

In a terminal navigate to path /etc/apache2/

```
cd /etc/apache2/
```

Check that you have the `php7.2-fpm` configuration available in `conf-available`

```
ls conf-available
```

If it is not available it may be installed via:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-fpm
```

enable `php7.2-fpm` configuration:

```
sudo a2enconf php7.2-fpm
```

This creates a link of the actual file `/etc/apache/conf-available/php7.2-fpm.conf` and places it in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` directory. By default ubuntu apache2 configuration includes all *.conf files from `/etc/apache2/*-enabled` directorys into the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

Now you will need to enable the `proxy` and `proxy_fcgi` modules

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
```

This will enable both modules as proxy.conf is a dependency of proxy_fcgi.

Now to complete, disable `php7.2 module`:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
```

Restart apache server

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Confirm configuration `"ip or domain"/phpinfo.php`

The line "Server API" will now confirm "    FPM/FastCGI    ".

PHP workload is now offloaded from apache process to an independent php server process.

This assumes default Ubuntu LAMP server settings. This does not take into account any previously enabled modules or configurations. Before making any changes to default conf files I recommend creating a backup copy for restoring default settings.

This method is similar for later Ubuntu releases with php7.3 or php 7.4

If any errors are encountered during restart check the apache2 logs files at `/var/log/apache2/` and php logs in `/var/log`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a way for me to test using php7.2-fpm with a single vhost before making the switch permenant for all vhosts? Or even a way to enable/disable php7.2/php7.2-fpm per vhost?

Comment: Yes, you could leave php7.2.conf module enabled.

Comment: Take a look at the `php7.2-fpm.conf` file. You could the copy <FilesMatch>"the code between tags"</FilesMatch> and put it into you site.conf file  inside the VirtualHost tags with php7.2.conf module enabled

Comment: I would suggest reading the Apache docs (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/)

Comment: Here is a link with similar info. Its for php7.4 but the idea is the same. [php-fpm](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-php-fpm-with-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04-google-cloud/)